# Android application crash when run after installation

Tags: android, eclipse

i am developing a native android application, i am using a third party api as well. The problem is, when i connect mobile (S3) to my machine and run application directly on mobile then it works fine. But when i copied the APK to android mobile, installed APP and run. Then on one of api call it crashes saying "Unfortunately AppName stopped working".

I could not find any way around to find out that what is the issue and what thing is the cause of application crash.

Anyone please suggest how to find out the problem or what can be the possible cuse. I am developing in Eclipse.

Comment: have you added the  activity in manifest files..

Comment: i am working on test application , thats why everything is on main activity that is added in manifest file.

Comment: @MarciCăşvan while running from eclipse it works fine. Problem appears after installation. Can view logcat after installation? i am new in android development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you set up a 5 minute quick BugSense library and free account and check the exception you get? http://www.bugsense.com/

Comment: Bugsense is not free and i cannot afford licensed log system :)

Comment: You can use the free account for 500 exceptions reported. I used it recently ;)

Comment: Nice, i have visited the site and docs but have some quick questions, errors will be sent online and i will it on website or can view locally from mobile? in which method i am supposed to close and flush session?

Comment: Just log in to Bugsense.com using your free account and view all the errors there. Haven't tried it from mobile but I think you should be able to see the content. :) Here is the example: http://www.bugsense.com/docs/android .Just add one line in onCreate() and one in onDestroy() and you're set

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your own log writing system via implementing `java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` within your app.

e.g.

```
public class myExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {

private UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultUEH;

private String localPath;



public myExceptionHandler(String localPath) {
    this.localPath = localPath;

    this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
}

@Override
public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
    final long ts = new Date().getTime();

    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(ts);

    final String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HH_mm_ss_SSS")
            .format(cal.getTime());

    final Writer result = new StringWriter();
    final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(result);
    e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
    String stacktrace = result.toString();
    printWriter.close();
    String filename = "logcat"+timestamp + ".txt";

    if (localPath != null) {

        writeToFile(stacktrace, filename);
    }

    defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e);

}

private void writeToFile(String stacktrace, String filename) {
    try {
        BufferedWriter bos = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(localPath
                + "/" + filename));
        bos.write(stacktrace);
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Call this handler from the MainActivity like this:

```
  Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new myExceptionHandler("Put your target directory/folder path where you would like to store the log file"));
```

Now you will have a logfile written whenever app crashs with in the folder that you have used in code.

Comment: what is recommended either i should write in memory card or mobile memory? and how i can assign path of memory card / phone memory?

Comment: @Tanveer In my case, I have my app folder created on external memory.I am targeting o.s 4.0 + and now a days most devices come with inbulit external memory. I think you can put them in external memory as those merely will be logs.

Answer (score 0):

Just connect your device to the PC and let the LogCat window in Eclipse open. Logcat messages will still be outputted to LogCat without actually debugging your app.

Comment: In fact my application works with a hardware device that is connected via usb port. that is why i cannot attach application to system while running because used is being used by that device